# Android IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, android, exception

I don't know what i did wrong, but I'm getting an "IndexOutOfBoundException" in my app. Here's my code and logcat:

//Code

```
public class GameView extends View {

  private Context myContext;
  private int scaledCardW;
  private int scaledCardH;
  private int screenH, screenW;
  private List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
  private List<Card> myHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
  private List<Card> oppHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
  private List<Card> discardPile = new ArrayList<Card>();

  private float scale;
  private Paint blackPaint;
  private int oppScore;
  private int myScore;

  private boolean myTurn;

  private int movingCardIdx = -1;
  private int movingX;
  private int movingY;

  private int validRank = 8;
  private int validSuit = 0;

  private Bitmap cardBack;
  private Bitmap nextCardButton;

  private ComputerPlayer computerPlayer = new ComputerPlayer();

  private int scoreThisHand = 0;

  public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    myContext = context;

    scale = myContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    blackPaint = new Paint();
    blackPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    blackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    blackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    blackPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    blackPaint.setTextSize(scale * 15);

    //myTurn = new Random().nextBoolean();
    //myTurn = true;
  }

  @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
      super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
      screenH = h;
      screenW = w;

      initCards();

      dealCards();

      Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(),R.drawable.card_back);

      nextCardButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.arrow_next);

      scaledCardW = screenW/8;
      scaledCardH = (int) (scaledCardW*1.28);

      cardBack = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, scaledCardW,scaledCardH,false);

      validRank = discardPile.get(0).getRank();
      validSuit = discardPile.get(0).getSuit();

      myTurn = new Random().nextBoolean();
      if(!myTurn)
      {
        makeComputerPlay();
      }
    }

  private void initCards()
  {
    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {

      for(int y = 102; y < 115; y++)
      {
        int tempId = y + (x * 100);

        Card tempCard = new Card(tempId);
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("card"+ tempId, "drawable",myContext.getPackageName());

        Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(),resourceId);

        scaledCardW = screenW/8;
        scaledCardH = (int) (scaledCardW*1.28);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap,scaledCardW, scaledCardH, false);


        tempCard.setBmp(scaledBitmap);
        deck.add(tempCard);
      }

    }

  }

  private void drawCard(List<Card> handToDraw)
  {
    handToDraw.add(0,deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);

    if(deck.isEmpty())
    {
      for(int x = discardPile.size() -1; x > 0; x --)
      {
        deck.add(discardPile.get(0));
        discardPile.remove(0);
        Collections.shuffle(deck, new Random());
      }
    }
  }

  private void dealCards()
  {
    Collections.shuffle(deck, new Random());

    for(int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
    {
      drawCard(myHand);
      //drawCard(oppHand);
    }
  }

  @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      //canvas.drawBitmap(deck.get(9).getBmp(), 80, 50,null);

      canvas.drawText("Computer Score: " + oppScore, 10, blackPaint.getTextSize() + 10, blackPaint);

      canvas.drawText("My Score: " + myScore, 10, (int)(screenH * 0.9) - blackPaint.getTextSize() - 10, blackPaint);



      for (int i = 0; i < oppHand.size(); i++)
      {
        canvas.drawBitmap(cardBack, i*(scale*5), blackPaint.getTextSize()+(50*scale), null);
      }

      canvas.drawBitmap(cardBack, (screenW/2)-cardBack.getWidth()-10, (screenH/2)-(cardBack.getHeight()/2), null);

      if (!discardPile.isEmpty())
      {
        canvas.drawBitmap(discardPile.get(0).getBmp(),(screenW/2)+10,(screenH/2)-(cardBack.getHeight()/2), null);
      }


      for (int i = 0; i < myHand.size(); i++) {
        if (i == movingCardIdx)
        {
          canvas.drawBitmap(myHand.get(i).getBmp(),
              movingX,
              movingY,
              null);
        }
        else
        {
          canvas.drawBitmap
            (myHand.get(i).getBmp(),
             i*(scaledCardW+5),
             screenH-blackPaint.
             getTextSize()-
             (50*scale), null);
        }
      }


      if (myHand.size() > 7)
      {
        canvas.drawBitmap(nextCardButton,
            screenW-nextCardButton.getWidth()-(30*scale),screenH-nextCardButton.getHeight()-scaledCardH-(90*scale),null);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < myHand.size(); i++)
      {
        if (i == movingCardIdx)
        {
          canvas.drawBitmap(myHand.get(i).getBmp(),movingX, movingY, null);
        }
        else
        {
          if(i < 7)
          {
            canvas.drawBitmap(myHand.get(i).getBmp(),i*(scaledCardW+5),screenH-blackPaint.getTextSize()-(50*scale),null);
          }
        }

      }


      invalidate();

    }

  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

      int eventaction = event.getAction();
      int X = (int)event.getX();
      int Y = (int)event.getY();
      switch (eventaction ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

          if(myTurn)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
              if (X > i*(scaledCardW+5) && X < i*(scaledCardW+5) + scaledCardW && Y > screenH-blackPaint.getTextSize()- (50*scale))
              {
                movingCardIdx = i;
                movingX = X-(int)(30*scale);
                movingY = Y-(int)(70*scale);
              }
            }

          }
          break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          movingX = X-(int)(30*scale);
          movingY = Y-(int)(70*scale);
          break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

          if (movingCardIdx > -1 && X > (screenW/2)-(100*scale) && X < (screenW/2)+(100*scale) && Y > (screenH/2)-(100*scale) && Y < (screenH/2)+(100*scale) &&
              (myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getRank() == 8 || myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getRank() ==
               validRank || myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getSuit() == validSuit))
          {
            validRank = myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getRank();
            validSuit = myHand.get(movingCardIdx).getSuit();
            discardPile.add(0, myHand.get(movingCardIdx));
            myHand.remove(movingCardIdx);

            if(myHand.isEmpty())
            {
              endHand();
            }
            else
            {
              if(validRank == 8)
              {
                showChooseSuitDialog();
              }
              else
              {
                myTurn = false;
                makeComputerPlay();
              }
            }
          }
          movingCardIdx = -1;

          if (movingCardIdx == -1 && myTurn && X > (screenW/2)-(100*scale) && X < (screenW/2)+(100*scale) &&
              Y > (screenH/2)-(100*scale) && Y < (screenH/2)+(100*scale))
          {
            if (checkForValidDraw())
            {
              drawCard(myHand);
            }
            else
            {
              Toast.makeText(myContext, "You have a valid play.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

          }

          if (myHand.size() > 7 && X > screenW-nextCardButton.getWidth()-(30*scale) && Y > screenH-nextCardButton.getHeight()-scaledCardH- (90*scale) &&
              Y < screenH-nextCardButton.getHeight()-scaledCardH - (60*scale))
          {
            Collections.rotate(myHand, 1);
          }

          break;
      }

      invalidate();
      return true;
    }

  private void showChooseSuitDialog()
  {
    final Dialog chooseSuitDialog = new Dialog(myContext);
    chooseSuitDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    chooseSuitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.choose_suit_dialog);
    final Spinner suitSpinner = (Spinner)chooseSuitDialog.findViewById(R.id.suitSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(myContext, R.array.suits,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    suitSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button okButton = (Button) chooseSuitDialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
        validSuit = (suitSpinner.
          getSelectedItemPosition()+1)*100;
        String suitText = "";
        if (validSuit == 100) {
        suitText = "Diamonds";
        } else if (validSuit == 200) {
        suitText = "Clubs";
        } else if (validSuit == 300) {
        suitText = "Hearts";
        } else if (validSuit == 400) {
        suitText = "Spades";
        }
        chooseSuitDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(myContext,"You chose " + suitText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        myTurn = false;
        makeComputerPlay();
        }
        });

    chooseSuitDialog.show();
  }

  private boolean checkForValidDraw()
  {
    boolean canDraw = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < myHand.size(); i++)
    {
      int tempId = myHand.get(i).getId();
      int tempRank = myHand.get(i).getRank();
      int tempSuit = myHand.get(i).getSuit();
      if (validSuit == tempSuit || validRank == tempRank || tempId == 108 || tempId == 208 ||tempId == 308 || tempId == 408)
      {
        canDraw = false;
      }
    }
    return canDraw;
  }


  private void makeComputerPlay()
  {
    int tempPlay = 0;
    while (tempPlay == 0)
    {
      tempPlay = computerPlayer.makePlay(oppHand,validSuit, validRank);
      if (tempPlay == 0)
      {
        drawCard(oppHand);
      }
    }
    if (tempPlay == 108 || tempPlay == 208 || tempPlay == 308 || tempPlay == 408)
    {
      validRank = 8;
      validSuit = computerPlayer.chooseSuit(oppHand);
      String suitText = "";
      if (validSuit == 100)
      {
        suitText = "Diamonds";
      }
      else if (validSuit == 200)
      {
        suitText = "Clubs";
      }
      else if (validSuit == 300)
      {
        suitText = "Hearts";
      }
      else if (validSuit == 400)
      {
        suitText = " Spades";
      }
      Toast.makeText(myContext, "Computer chose " + suitText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
      validSuit = Math.round((tempPlay/100) * 100);
      validRank = tempPlay - validSuit;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oppHand.size(); i++)
    {

      Card tempCard = oppHand.get(i);
      if (tempPlay == tempCard.getId())
      {
        discardPile.add(0, oppHand.get(i));
        oppHand.remove(i);
      }
    }

    if(oppHand.isEmpty())
    {
      endHand();
    }

    myTurn = true;

  }



  private void updateScores()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < myHand.size(); i++)
    {
      oppScore += myHand.get(i).getScoreValue();
      scoreThisHand += myHand.get(i).getScoreValue();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < oppHand.size(); i++)
    {
      myScore += oppHand.get(i).getScoreValue();
      scoreThisHand += oppHand.get(i).getScoreValue();
    }

  }

  private void endHand()
  {
    final Dialog endHandDialog = new Dialog(myContext);
    endHandDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    endHandDialog.setContentView(R.layout.end_hand_dialog);
    updateScores();
    TextView endHandText = (TextView)endHandDialog.findViewById(R.id.endHandText);
    if (myHand.isEmpty())
    {
      if(myScore >= 300)
      {
        endHandText.setText("You reached " + myScore + " points. You won! Would you like to play again?");

      }
      else
      {
        endHandText.setText("You went out and got " + scoreThisHand + " points!");
      }
    }
    else if (oppHand.isEmpty())
    {
      if (oppScore >= 300)
      {
        endHandText.setText("The computer reached " + oppScore + " points. Sorry, you lost. Would you like to play again?");
      }
      else
      {
        endHandText.setText("The computer went out and got " + scoreThisHand + " points.");
      }
    }


    Button nextHandButton = (Button)endHandDialog.findViewById(R.id.nextHandButton);
    if (oppScore >= 300 || myScore >= 300)
    {
      nextHandButton.setText("New Game");
    }

    nextHandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
        if (oppScore >= 300 || myScore >= 300)
        {
        myScore = 0;
        oppScore = 0;
        }

        initNewHand();
        endHandDialog.dismiss();
        }

        });

    endHandDialog.show();

  }

  private void initNewHand() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    scoreThisHand = 0;
    if (myHand.isEmpty())
    {
      myTurn = true;
    }
    else if (oppHand.isEmpty())
    {
      myTurn = false;
    }
    deck.addAll(discardPile);
    deck.addAll(myHand);
    deck.addAll(oppHand);

    discardPile.clear();
    myHand.clear();
    oppHand.clear();

    dealCards();
    drawCard(discardPile);

    validSuit = discardPile.get(0).getSuit();
    validRank = discardPile.get(0).getRank();

    if (!myTurn)
    {
      makeComputerPlay();
    }
  }


}
```

//Here's my LogCat

```
 error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 7% free 2395K/2572K, paused 88ms, total 91ms
 Grow heap (frag case) to 3.210MB for 770432-byte allocation
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3147K/3328K, paused 100ms, total 100ms
 GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3265K/3448K, paused 23ms+25ms, total 186ms
 Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 GC_CONCURRENT freed 245K, 11% free 3524K/3920K, paused 75ms+53ms, total 455ms
 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 194ms
 GC_CONCURRENT freed 315K, 12% free 3673K/4160K, paused 14ms+29ms, total 370ms
 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 212ms
 GC_CONCURRENT freed 287K, 11% free 3853K/4320K, paused 78ms+64ms, total 441ms
 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 182ms
 GC_CONCURRENT freed 352K, 12% free 3961K/4500K, paused 9ms+28ms, total 363ms
 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 243ms
 GC_CONCURRENT freed 314K, 11% free 4105K/4600K, paused 98ms+61ms, total 434ms
 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 234ms
 GC_CONCURRENT freed 352K, 12% free 4268K/4820K, paused 9ms+80ms, total 530ms
 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 215ms
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 193K, 12% free 4244K/4820K, paused 68ms, total 70ms
 Grow heap (frag case) to 4.583MB for 316480-byte allocation
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 4553K/5132K, paused 147ms, total 147ms
 Shutting down VM
 threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
      at com.example.crazyeights.GameView.onSizeChanged(GameView.java:94)
      at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:14094)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14006)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Sending signal. PID: 929 SIG: 9
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 8% free 2395K/2576K, paused 326ms, total 332ms
 Grow heap (frag case) to 3.210MB for 770432-byte allocation
 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3147K/3332K, paused 79ms, total 79ms
 GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3273K/3452K, paused 31ms+29ms, total 163ms
 Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: So, you're expecting someone to read and understand more than 500 loc for an issue that occurs in line 94 of the corresponding view without actually pointing out which line it is?

Comment: HOw do I do that? I'm new to Android

Comment: at com.example.crazyeights.GameView.onSizeChanged(GameView.java:94)---write which one is line number 94 in your GameView class

Answer (score 2):

In your `onSizeChanged()`, you access the first element of `discardPile` with `get(0)` but the `discardPile` is empty.

Comment: Should I add a card(s) on the first element?

Comment: I don't know. There's too much code to read through to figure out why the `get(0)` calls are there in the first place. Maybe an `isEmpty()` check would help.

Comment: The question is, how do you want the screen to look when there are no cards on the discard pile.

Comment: I want the screen to look empty when there are no cards on the discard pile.

Comment: Well, then you have to take account of that case in your `onSizeChanged` method.